# bash [[ [a] == [a] ]] not true? square bracket affect compare result

Tags: bash, string-comparison

Anyone know why this happens? Is this a bug of bash?

```
x='mnt:[4026532411]'

[[ $x == $x ]] && echo OK
```

I am expecting result `OK`, but it did not.

Of course, this works

```
[[ "$x" == "$x" ]] && echo OK
```

But as I know, bash [[ ]] have a merit that no need to quote var when compare.

```
x='a b'
[[ $x == $x ]] && echo OK
```

works.

Ironical things is

```
x='mnt:[4026532411]'

[[ $x != $x ]] && echo Oh my god
```

result is Oh my god

Comment: Just to follow up the answers with a look at the question title: `[[ [a] == [a] ]]` will not be "true" because the left-hand operand is the literal 3-character string "[a]" and the right-hand operand is a pattern that can only match the letter "a"

Comment: Conversely, `[ [a] = [a] ]` **is** true, because `[` is different from `[[`: the `=` operator in `[` is only a string equality operator.

Comment: `x='mnt:4'; y='mnt:[0123456]'; [[ $x == $y ]] && echo OK`

Comment: "...no need to quote var when compare" - I don't think that was good advice. I would suggest quoting anyway whenever you want to do a pure string comparison, for precisely this reason.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The unquoted right-hand side of `==` and `!=` is treated as a pattern, not a literal string. `mnt:[4026532411]` will match `mnt:` followed by exactly *one* of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6, since the patterns `mnt:[4026532411]` and `mnt:[0123456]` are equivalent. To match the lieral string, you need to quote the expansion.

```
x='mnt:[4026532411]'

[[ $x == "$x" ]] && echo OK
```

Comment: So basically it's a complete lie that `[[` `]]` avoids the need for quoting?

Comment: @Mehrdad  Not entirely. Quoting in `[` is meant for countering word-splitting. That's what people refer to when they mention `[[` doesn't need quotes. And in chepner's answer the unquoted `$x` on left hand side is perfectly fine - it doesn't need quotes there. But again, there's different issue - `[[` treats right hand side of `==` as pattern. So....context matters, I guess

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: I mean I guess I'm saying the context *doesn't* matter; either you need to quote, or you don't.

Comment: The *normal* reasons for quoting (to avoid word-splitting and path expansion) don't apply, but the fact that `==` and `!=` inside `[[...]]` can perform pattern matching introduces a *new* reason to quote.

Comment: Of course you don't need to quote if the right hand side is a pattern.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I agree, this was a bad decision of mine. For some reason I thought, it would be easier to redefine a pair of variables at the top of my script. But I don't think so anymore =)

Answer (score 6):

What you are seeing is do do this sentence from the `bash` man page:

> When the == and != operators are used, the string to the right of
>   the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to  the
>   rules  described  below under  Pattern  Matching,  as if the extglob
>   shell option were enabled.

As you may already know, `[...]` in the shell allows matching from a
group of characters.  That is, given the files:

```
$ ls
fileA fileB fileC fileD
```

Running `ls file[AB]` will yield:

```
fileA fileB
```

So in your expression, `mnt:[1234]` is interpreted in a similar
fashion.