# How to do string equality with AND operator in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
if [ $string1 = $string2 -a $string3 = $string4 ]; then
```

results [: too many arguments. 
How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

With the single bracket test, `[ .. ]`, you should use quotes around the variable names in the test brackets. Otherwise Bash will break the string on any spaces.

With:

```
$ s1="one two"
$ s2="one two"
```

If you do not quote your variable:

```
$ [ $s1 = $s2 ]; echo $?
-bash: [: too many arguments
```

But if you quote -- all is good:

```
$ [ "$s1" = "$s2" ]; echo $?
0
```

(`0` means `True` in this case)

You can also use the Bash `[[ ... ]]` two bracket test and not use `"quotes"` [SOMTIMES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002801/bash-a-a-not-true-square-bracket-affect-compare-result):

```
$ [[ $s1 == $s2 ]]; echo $?
0
```

For the 'and' part, you can use `&&` either inside or outside the `[[ ... ]]` square braces:

```
$ s3="three"
$ s4="four"
$ [[ $s1 == $s2 ]] && [[ $s3 == $s4 ]]; echo $?
1
$ [[ $s1 == $s2 && $s3 == $s4 ]]; echo $?
1
```

But really -- it is best to quote all the time.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40431336/298607) SO post.

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment to @AndreGelinas, you should double-quote at least the variables on the right of `==`, even though it's in `[[ ]]`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002801/bash-a-a-not-true-square-bracket-affect-compare-result) for an example of why. But I really recommend double-quoting everything, to avoid having to keep track of where it's safe to leave variables unquoted.

Answer (score 0):

Or if strictly Bash/Ksh

```
#!/bin/bash

s1="one two"
s2="one two"
s3="three four"
s4="three four"


if [[ $s1 == $s2 && $s3 == $s4 ]]; then
        echo "All equals"
else
        echo "Some differences"
fi
```

Within [[ ]] there would be no word splitting normally and thus no need for quoting. Also, "&&" is generally preferred instead of "-a" for AND nowadays.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I recommend using double-quotes around variables, even in `[[ ]]`, because in some cases it matters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002801/bash-a-a-not-true-square-bracket-affect-compare-result) for an example). In this case, you could get away with double-quoting only the variables to the right of `==` (leaving the ones on the left unquoted), but keeping track of the rules and exceptions is really more trouble than it's worth -- just double-quote everything and you won't have to worry about it.